# Angular 8 subscribe to an emitted event using emit giving an error of undefined ON method

Tags: angular, eventemitter, angular8

**EDIT**

I have at the `main-navbar.component` the main menu of the whole app, which contains a drop list to change the default language of the app:

```
<form [formGroup]="langForm" role="form" *ngIf="langForm">
     <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select formControlName="selectLang" [(ngModel)]="selectedLang" (selectionChange)="OnChangeLang()">
             <mat-option value="en">English</mat-option>
             <mat-option value="ar">عربي</mat-option>
         </mat-select>
     </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

In `OnChangeLang()` method, I need to change the default language and default `dir` of the app that are saved in a service called `global-var.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GlobarVarService {
  defaultLang:string = "en";
  defaultDir:string = "ltr";
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

These variables are connected to variables at `app.component.ts`.

I need to use `BehaviorSubject` to subscribe to the change made on these variable so it directly change the display of my app.

**END EDIT**

I have the following event to be emitted when a user change application default language:

```
@Output() changeLangOutput= new EventEmitter();
OnChangeLang()
{
  let lang = this.langForm.get('selectLang').value;
  console.log(lang)
  this.globalVar.defaultLang = lang;
  this.changeLangOutput.emit('changeLang', lang);

}
```

At the `app.module.ts`, I am trying to subscribe to this change using:

`@Input() subscribeLangEvent: string;`

but I have no idea how to do it, as `subscribeLangEvent.on('changeLang`) giving an error of `on is undefined function`.

Comment: `@Input` and `@Output` don't work as you think they do. You should probably be using `BehaviorSubject`s for your specific use case.

Comment: @Sidd so in my case `changeLangOutput` how could be used with `.next` in `app.component.ts` ?

Comment: As it is in the `main-nav` component where the user would change default language into other, and the direction of the app is set in `app.component.ts` so we should subscribe to that event at `app.component.ts` too

Comment: @SiddAjmera I am editing the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming from your comments that `MainNavComponent` is the child of the `AppComponent`.

Here's how you'd implement the feature:

In the Child Component, you'd expose an `@Output` property that you'd emit the value from:

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-nav',
  templateUrl: './main-nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main-nav.component.css']
})
export class MainNavComponent {

  @Output() changeLangOutput= new EventEmitter();

  langForm: FormGroup;
  languageOptions: Array<string> = [
    'English',
    'Hindi',
    'Spanish',
    'French',
  ];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.langForm = this.fb.group({
      selectLang: ['English']
    });
  }

  onChangeLang() {
    let lang = this.langForm.get('selectLang').value;
    this.changeLangOutput.emit(lang);
  }

}
```

And in the `AppComponent` Template, you'd listen to the event like this:

```
<app-main-nav 
  (changeLangOutput)="onLanguageChange($event)">
</app-main-nav>
```

And in the `AppComponent` Class, define a method named `onLanguageChange($event)`

---

#### UPDATE:

Since you want multiple things from the selected value, you should have an array of objects instead of an array of strings.

And when the user selects a different language, you'll get the value of the field as a string. But then you'll have to get the whole object from the list by using `find`:

```
...

export class MainNavComponent {

  ...

  languageOptions: Array<{ id: number; name: string, direction: string }> = [
    { id: 1, name: 'English', direction: 'ltr'},
    ...
  ];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.langForm = this.fb.group({
      selectLang: ['English']
    });
  }

  getLanguageObject(selectedLanguage) {
    return this.languageOptions.find(language => language.name === selectedLanguage);
  }

  onChangeLang() {
    const lang = this.langForm.get('selectLang').value;
    const selectedLanguage = this.getLanguageObject(lang);
    this.changeLangOutput.emit(selectedLanguage);
  }

}
```

---

> Here's an Updated [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/parent-child-communication-with-input-and-output) for your ref.

Comment: Sorry your stackblitz is missing codes at `app.component.ts`

Comment: Ok I have done it. The values of `lang` and `dir` in globalVar service are changed, but the direction of the app is not.

Comment: `direction` of the App? What exactly do you mean?

Comment: When in english the direction is `ltr`, in arabic should be `rtl`. In my `main-nav-component` we have inside the method the following line `      this.globalVar.defaultLang = lang;` and at `(changeLangOutput)="onLanguageChange($event)"` I've set that if `en` dir=ltr and vice versa

Comment: at the console both `dir` and `lang` vars are changing but the display is not.